# schema validation get value from sum of another value of json

Tags: json, karate

I have json file contains data below, and what i want is to validate if `amount` value is sum of `bills[*]. total_electricity_bill` + `admin_charge`. Is there a simple way to do that directly inside json file?

```
{
    "amount": "68671",
    "admin_charge": "60000",
    "stan": "633105",
    "bills": [
        {
            "produk": "PLNPOSTPAID",
            "total_electricity_bill": "00000008671",
        },
        {
            "produk": "PLNPOSTPAID",
            "total_electricity_bill": "00000000000",
        },
        {
            "produk": "PLNPOSTPAID",
            "total_electricity_bill": "00000000000",
        }
    ],
    "material_number": "",
    "status": true,
    "response_code": "00",
    "rc": "00",
    "trx_id": ""
}
```

Comment: ook i have already accepted my previous question

Comment: @PeterThomas is there a simpler way to that ?

Comment: no, unless you use magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is an much more elegant way to do it, but the following code works:

> ```
> * def resp = 
> """
> {
>     "amount": "68671",
>     "admin_charge": "60000",
>     "stan": "633105",
>     "bills": [
>         {
>             "produk": "PLNPOSTPAID",
>             "total_electricity_bill": "00000008671",
>         },
>         {
>             "produk": "PLNPOSTPAID",
>             "total_electricity_bill": "00000000000",
>         },
>         {
>             "produk": "PLNPOSTPAID",
>             "total_electricity_bill": "00000000000",
>         }
>     ],
>     "material_number": "",
>     "status": true,
>     "response_code": "00",
>     "rc": "00",
>     "trx_id": ""
> }
> """
> * def sum = 0    
> * def fun = function(x){ var temp = karate.get('sum') + parseFloat(x); karate.set('sum', temp) }
> * def fnum = function(x){ return parseFloat(x) }    
> * def teb = get resp.bills[*].total_electricity_bill
> * eval karate.forEach(teb, fun)
> * def ac = get resp.admin_charge
> * fun(ac)
>
> * match sum == fnum(resp.amount)
> ```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want do this directly inside my json file :D

Comment: @YudistiraSugandi this is the correct answer. you have unrealistic expectations. if it makes you feel any better, all this logic can be put into a JS function and *then* you can do this "directly inside the JSON" read the docs and figure it out

Answer (score -1):

Not using karate, but using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), it's rather easy to perform the check:

```
<file jq '([.admin_charge,.bills[].total_electricity_bill|tonumber]|add)==(.amount|tonumber)'
```

The jq command builds an array with both `admin_charge` and all `total_electricity` fields converted to numbers in order to check against the `amount` field.

It returns `true` with the given example (or `false` if the sum would be different).

Comment: how about using karate ?? or i can combine jq with karatedsl ?? Because now i am using karatedsl :D